# Django requested URL was not found on this server in TestClass

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

My TestClass looks like:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client

class TestGetSomething(TestCase):
    def test_get_first_url(self):
        path = "some/long/path"
        client = Client()
        response = client.get(path=path)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But `assertEquals` raises the exception, `404 != 200`.
When i wrote `print(response.__dict__)` i have noted request that fields:

```
'_closable_objects': [<WSGIRequest: GET 'somelong/path'>]
'request': {'PATH_INFO': 'some/long/path', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET', 'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http', 'QUERY_STRING': ''}
'templates': [<django.template.base.Template object at 0x7f4b33ac17f0>], 'context': [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'request_path': '/somelong/path/', 'exception': 'Resolver404'}]
```

As you can see the part of paths does not have the slash between 'some' and 'long'
When i am trying to get the page by URL manually (using a browser) everything goes OK
In my Django app i do not use nothing except of Model and ModelAdmin. Even urls.py is clear.
Everybody now how can i fixed it?
Any additional code I'll add if it necessary.

Comment: What is the `urls.py`? What are the paths that are valid?

Comment: You probably need to add a leading slash here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paths should **start with a slash `/`**. In fact in your browser it is no different, since if you write `localhost:8000/some/long/path` the first slash is simply part of the `path`. Furthermore a browser will typically "fix" a url like `example.com` to `example.com/`.

You thus need to write it like:

```
class TestGetSomething(TestCase):

    def test_get_first_url(self):
        # start with a slash
        path = "/some/long/path"
        client = Client()
        response = client.get(path=path)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```